# Safari div not overflowing properly

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to create a simple page with one sidebar and on content area, like this

```
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content">
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using this stylesheet

```
#mainWrapper {
background: #F6F7F9;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #D6D8D8;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #D6D8D8;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 181px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But for some reason the **content** area doesn't overflow properly on the Safari browser, leaving a very large margin on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-left: 181px;` from `#content`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SC7Md/2/)**

Comment: if i do that when the content is bigger it wil go under the sidebar.

Comment: When the content is bigger than what?

Comment: never mind i overlooked something, thanks for your reply it worked